# Input keydown event is firing button click of another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I hope I'm missing something obvious here...

This only happens in IE9 (go figure)

I'm using KnockoutJS(2.1 RC) and JQuery(1.7.2)

I have an input element on a page (actually lots of them) and whenever I hit the "enter" key, it fires the `click` event of the first button element on the page.

http://jsfiddle.net/HZymG/2/

Comment: That's because it's probably a submit button, and it has been given default focus by the browser (IE). When you press enter, it behaves as if you clicked on the button. Look on [so] for posts about preventing submissions from the enter key for a myriad of different solutions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `type="button"` to your `<button>` elements. If you omit that in IE, it will treat them as `<button type="submit" />` elements.

Updated your jsFiddle to show that this is the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/HZymG/3/

Comment: Yes,  I was having a similar issue in all browsers where if the button was focused and you pressed enter it would fire up the click event twice (at least when wired up using knockout.    The type="button" addition to the markup worked like charm.